# How do I fix the "no such column" in sqlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Before I added the UserUid field it worked just fine , now it keeps crashing and I dont't know why . It is a database and i fixed it to select from specific current user but it tells me that the column doesn't exist.

I already recreated the Sqlite db , no luck

The error I am getting is at the GetCountCart() but I think the problem isn't there

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static String DB_NAME="OrderMeDB.db";
private static int DB_VER=1;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VER );
}

public List<OrderModel> getCarts(String userUid)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"UserUid","DenumireProdus" , "Cantitate" , "Pret"};
    String sqlTable = "Comanda";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db , sqlSelect , "UserUid=?",new String[]{userUid},null,null,null);

    final List<OrderModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            result.add(new OrderModel(
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UserUid")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DenumireProdus")),
                    c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Cantitate")),
                    c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Pret"))
            ));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean checkFoodExists(String userUid , String denumireProdus)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String SQLQuery = String.format("SELECT * FROM Comanda WHERE UserUid='%s' AND DenumireProdus='%s'",userUid,denumireProdus);
    cursor = db.rawQuery(SQLQuery,null);
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        flag = true;
    else
        flag = false;
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
public void addToCart(OrderModel order)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Comanda(UserUid,DenumireProdus,Cantitate,Pret) VALUES('%s',%s','%s','%s');",
            order.getUserUid(),
            order.getDenumireProdus(),
            order.getCantitate(),
            order.getPret());
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public void cleanCart(String userUid)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("DELETE FROM Comanda WHERE UserUid='%s'",userUid);
    db.execSQL(query);

}
public void removeFromCart(String userUid,String denumireProdus)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("DELETE FROM Comanda WHERE UserUid='%s' AND DenumireProdus='%s'",userUid,denumireProdus);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
public void increaseCart(String userUid,String denumireProdus)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("UPDATE Comanda SET Cantitate= Cantitate+1 WHERE UserUid='%s' AND DenumireProdus='%s'",userUid,denumireProdus);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
public int getCountCart(String userUid) {
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comanda WHERE UserUid='%s'",userUid);
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return count;

}
public int getItemCount(String denumireProdus , String userUid) {
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comanda WHERE UserUid='s' AND DenumireProdus='%s' ",userUid,denumireProdus);
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return count;

}
}
```

This is the error I am getting :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Food}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UserUid (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comanda WHERE UserUid='QM9amP6CX4g24wrq7Hu2'

Comment: Uninstall your app so the old version is cleared and new version gets copied.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you should never build SQL statements by replacing variables - it's inefficient and vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements with bind variables instead: Also, you've got an error in `UserUid='s'`.

Comment: It just doesn't recognize my UserUid column in the database , I tried everything

Comment: @akaMishu uninstall the app from the device and rerun so the table is recreated.

Comment: already did that , no luck..

Comment: @akaMishu check your manifest, if there is a line: `android:allowBackup="true"` change it to `android:allowBackup="false"`. If this does not work then the db was not copied from assets.

Comment: It seems to work now thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

For my understandings the error message says that you haven't added the column to the table. I'm not that familiar with Java but I would check if the column is created and in the right table.

Comment: It is made with Sqlite and has the column with UserUid in it , I just don't understand why wouldn't it recognize the column , it's above my understanding . The column exists but the program tells me it doesn't ...

Comment: Try a `SELECT * FROM comanda` only. If the column isn't showing up there you need to pay attention to the creation of the column.

Comment: It worked before I created the UserUid field , it doesn't want to create the field I don't understand why ...

Comment: I know, you said that before. But just do a `SELECT *` to check if the column exists. If not try to create the column again.

Comment: I don't really understand how I should do to see that

Comment: You just need to send this query to your database: `SELECT * FROM comanda`
This should output you everything from the table comanda. If there is no column named `UserUid` then you need to add this column to the table. **Currently you don't have the column** `UserUid` **in your database.**